# Getting access to field using its name in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes

I have two layers: `Data` and `Thresholds`. `Data` is a point vector layer (GeoPackage) that has hundreds of fields. `Thresholds` is a csv table with three threshold values for each field. My goal is to create a new field in `Data` that would be a classification value. I need to check if any value of a feature in `Data` exceeds the threshold value of the same field in `Thresholds`. For example, if any `Data` value exceeds the first threshold value in the corresponding field in `Thresholds`, the classification value would be 1. Or if it exceeded the third threshold value, the classification would be 3. So I will have to loop through the values in `Thresholds` for each field in each object in `Data`. A couple nested loops, no biggie here.

The way I want to do this is to take the name of the field in `Data` and check if there is such a field in `Thresholds`. If there is, then I will loop through the field and change the value in `Data`. It is possible that in the future, `Data` will contain fields that are not in `Thresholds`.

How do I get access to a fields name, and how do I get access to a field using just the name?

Comment: You first check if the field name exists like here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299263/qgis-3-0-2-check-if-a-field-exists-in-a-layer-in-python/299289#299289 And then, if the index is different to -1, you can access the field using `layer.fields().field("my_field_name")`. See the [docs](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFields.html).